# SQL Server order by clause issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am trying to get an order by clause that returns "standings" that is a varchar and looks similar to these values:

````
9-7-0
10-6-0
7-9-0
11-5-0
10-6-0
8-8-0
11-5-0
```
````

A normal `order by PlayersRecord` wasn't giving me the highest to lowest in the "wins" (first number in string) and was giving me this:

```
10-6-0
10-6-0
11-5-0
11-5-0
7-9-0
8-8-0
9-7-0
```

So I tried to use this in the order clause `order by substring(PlayersRecord, 1, (charindex('-', PlayersRecord) - 1))`

But it is returning the exact same results as the first order by clause?

Is there any way to accomplish this and get this result?

```
11-5-0
11-5-0
10-6-0
10-6-0
9-7-0
8-8-0
7-9-0
```

Comment: The first result *is* giving you the correct order, `'10-6-0'` *does* have a **lower** value than `'9-7-0'` as `'1'` is **lower** than `'9'`; that's how strings are ordered. The real problem here appear to be that you are storing delimited numerical data in a `varchar`, so the *real* solution is likely to fix the design. Store the values in 3 different columns and as a numerical datatype, such as an `int`.

Comment: So I may have found the solution but still hoping to have someone verify I am not getting misleading results in the future just because it worked here on current data that will change over time. I edited the clause to be as follows: order by convert(int, substring(PlayersRecord, 1, (charindex('-', PlayersRecord) - 1))) desc

I had to add the 'desc' because it was returning lowest to highest and I want highest to lowest values. and I now get this:
11-5-0
11-5-0
11-5-0
10-6-0
10-6-0
9-7-0
8-8-0
7-9-0

TIA! Rick...

Comment: You haven't found a "solution", you found a workaround for this inappropriate data model. Fixing the data model would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert your string into a `hierarchyid`

**Example**

```
Select * 
 from  YourTable
 order by try_convert(hierarchyid,'/'+replace([PlayersRecord],'-','/')+'/') desc
```

**Returns**

```
PlayersRecord
11-5-0
11-5-0
10-6-0
10-6-0
9-7-0
8-8-0
7-9-0
```

Comment: Thanks John. Would that be better option than what I discovered?
Rick...

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comments, fix your design, fix the problem. Don't store delimited data in your database and don't store data you need to act like a numerical value as a `varchar`. Split them into separate columns, store them in an appropriate data type, and if you "must" have the delimited value as well then add it as a calculated column instead:

```sql
--Sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (WinsLossesDraws varchar(20));
GO
--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('9-7-0'),
      ('10-6-0'),
      ('7-9-0'),
      ('11-5-0'),
      ('10-6-0'),
      ('8-8-0'),
      ('11-5-0');
GO
--Add new columns with appropraite data type (int)
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Wins int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Losses int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Draws int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
GO
--UPDATE the new columns with the correct values. Assume wins-losses-draws and all 3 are always present.
UPDATE YT
SET Wins = PARSENAME(V.R,3),
    Losses = PARSENAME(V.R,2),
    Draws = PARSENAME(V.R,1)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(YT.WinsLossesDraws,'-','.')))V(R);
GO
--Drop old column
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN WinsLossesDraws;
GO
--Recreate old column as a calculated one
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD WinsLossesDraws AS CONCAT_WS('-',Wins,Losses,Draws) PERSISTED;
--If you're on an old version of SQL Server use CONCAT (and STUFF)
GO
--Get data in the order you expect
SELECT WinsLossesDraws
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY Wins DESC,
         Draws DESC,
         Losses DESC;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d342701d6f4b9cb95e2b8b5e45da222)